# Strange Vertical Grid in TiKZ bar plots

Tags: pgfplots

I've trying to make a set of bar plots using TiKZ and `pgfplots` but for some unknown reason, the plot displays a vertical grid in X = 1, even when there is no grid added to the graph.

Is there a way to solve this? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 xmin = 0, xmax = 4,
 ymin = 0, ymax = 0.2,
 yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
 xlabel = X, ylabel = Y,
 ybar interval=1,
 bar width=25pt,
 legend style={cells={anchor=center, fill}, nodes={inner sep=1,below=-1.1ex}},area legend,
 legend pos=outer north east
 ]
 \addplot [color = red, fill = red, ybar]
    coordinates{(1,0.1632003)
                };
 \addplot [color = green, fill = green, ybar]
    coordinates{(2,0.132558)
                };
  \addplot [color = blue, fill = blue, ybar]
    coordinates{(3,0.1173594)
                };
 \draw [black, thick] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:7,0);               
 \legend{A, B, C}
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And a preview:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Edit: added `documentclass{article}` as suggested by @Jubobs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ybar interval` requires at least two coordinates to draw an **interval**. But then you switch back to `ybar`. Hence zero width `ybar interval` guides.